# How to load bash completion file in debian postinst script

Tags: debian, bash-completion

I have a small debian package that includes a bash completion file which is copied in the /etc/bash_completion.d folder.

After installation, the bash completion file is not "loaded". I have to type in the terminal:

> source /etc/bash_completion.d/mycompletionfile

I would like to avoid this with the postinst script. How should I do that?

Thank you

Comment: did you use `dh_bash-completion` for installation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

dh_bash-completion /etc/bash_completion.d/mycompletionfile in the postinst would be the good way?

Comment: The manpage says: "If a file named debian/package.bash-completion exists, then different actions are performed". Sounds to me that it should work automagically if the file has the correct name, maybe needs a dependency to bash-completion in the DEBIAN file and maybe the line `dh $@ --with bash-completion` in the rules file, but I'm not sure as I never used it, just saw that this debhelper exists. It might also just copy the file, and you are where you started.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Debian New Maintainers Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#customrules), you have to

1. add the `bash-completion` package in `Build-Depends`
2. add `dh $@ --with bash-completion` to `debian/rules`
3. create a file `debian/package.bash-completion` (and read `man dh_bash-completion`)

Comment: As of debhelper compat level 12, there's no need to change the debian/rules file at all. You only have to add two packages to Build-Depends (or Build-Depends-Indep): `bash-completion` and `dh-sequence-bash-completion`, which has the same effect as adding the --with flag to the dh invocation in debian/rules. That, and adding a package.bash-completion to the debian folder, will also fix the destination folder for your completion file; packages are supposed to place them in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, the folder in /etc is for user completion files only.

Answer (score 0):

Bash completion files are loaded at shell startup. If you install a new completion file, it won't be automatically loaded in existing shells where you have no other choice than source it or `source /etc/bash_completion`. Your new completion should be available in new shells without any special operation, though.